# C# windows Application attachmentFilename

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a working SQL connection here:

```
SqlConnection conn = 
   new SqlConnection(@"server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;
                       AttachDbFilename=C:\Seach ENGINE (June 22, 2015)\SE\SE\MainDatabase.mdf;
                       Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

but the problem is I need to provide the complete path. Unlike asp.net, all I have to do is to add `|DataDirectory|` to it and include the database name ..

Then I tried to use the `|DataDirectory|` in this connection string and I get an error:

> invalid value for key 'attachDbFilename'

I published my application and I can't locate the database now because I installed it in a different computer.. so the `attachDbFilename` is not true ..

If the `DataDirectory` is not working is there any other code that I can use similar to data directory?

Comment: Both machines are connected?

Comment: Why you are not using IP?

Comment: Why don't you map a drive letter to the network folder where your database resides?

Answer (score 1):

AttachDbFilename is used with local database. If you have remote database then the connection string will [be different](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/) . Have a look at article - [How to configure SQL Server 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/914277) to allow remote connections.

[Access mdf file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

As you see here

> System.Data.SqlClient resolves the substitution strings into full
>   paths against the local computer file system. Therefore, remote
>   server, HTTP, and UNC path names are not supported. An exception is
>   thrown when the connection is opened if the server is not located on
>   the local computer.

If you want to connect to an already-running SQL Server Express instance on another computer over TCP, then you need to set-up TCP connections on that server first. Note that you cannot use AttachDbFilename either because that option only applies to "user instances" of SQL Server Express.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

SqlConnection require you to specify the fully-qualified name of the 
db that is being attached.
No way around that.